Can viruses infect already archived files?
I think my PC (windows) is infected. A few days back, I noticed a strange program running in my PC and some lagging. Although this happened only once (the program never run again after several reboots) and Windows Defender didn't find anything, I still suspect whether my PC is infected or not.
Considering my PC as infected, is it possible that the virus goes inside previously healthy archived files (e.g. RAR). I have so many archived files. Is it necessary that I delete and download all of them again to make sure they're safe? Or archived files are already safe from infection in this scenario?

Is it possible, it’s absolutely possible, but what would the purpose be for the malware to do this? If you cannot detect it, it will steal your authentication cookies, that’s of course if you are actually infected. I have never actually seen someone actually infected if they ask a question and describe a situation like you have in the 13 years I have been part of this community. Especially when they are unable to detect the malware or any actual activity or evidence they were infected

You should be running something like malware bytes permanently.    Google for Kaspersky for free tools to check for infection manually.

Yes.
Just yes.
It is best that you shutdown that PC. Backup your important files (and scan the for viruses), and reinstall windows freshly.
The best way I can give is using Hiren's Boot CD PE.
The boot disc has many antivirus tools, and uses WinPE, so you can easily back up your files, scan them for malware, and reinstall windows.
Try a malwarebytes scan maybe.

After saving data, remove all partitions from the drive, leaving it all as empty space, before attempting reinstallation de novo. Note that there's some malware that can be embedded in firmware: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogoFAIL, in which case, a new motherboard is needed.

I think this answer lacks nuance and doesn't really answer the question.    Also, following advice won't neccessarily prevent reinfection in the unlikely even the system is compromised - as the root cause of how the system was compromised has not been found.

Per ramhound comment It is technically possible to do this, however the use cases for this are limited, so it is very unlikely.   If you are a "high value target" and something is known about your usage patterns it is conceivable that an attacker could be doing something to increase the possibilty of long term access, but its unlikely.
A much more likely possibility  (which would seem to almost but not quite meet your usage case) would be a Cryptolocker type scenario, where the files/part of the files are encrypted and once the process is complete you are asked to pay a ransom.  Of-course these files would not be able to be opened.    Unfortunately this is a fairly common vector, which is why offline/immutable backups are now commonplace.
One thing which can help is that many downloads will publish SHA checksums - so you may be able to create and search and compare checksums of files to see if their integrity has been compromised.
